# Does stack rerun hpack not only on build but already on change?

Tags: git, haskell, haskell-stack, hpack

I'm using stack with hpack so that `.cabal` file is generated from hpack's `package.yaml`. Often times as I want to switch branch I struggle with constantly changing `.cabal` file.

- I run `git restore *.cabal`. Working tree is in unstaged state.
- Immediately after I run `git switch branch` but get

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
> Package.cabal

- The error message is correct as `.cabal` has changed and now there are uncommited changes. I didn't observe the exact circumstances but here my `Paths_Package` differs between the branches.

Why does this happen? Does `stack` rerun `hpack` on every modification? Isn't it enough to recompute `.cabal` before build?

This behaviour is frustrating and how I'm solving it for now is running as a single command:

`git restore *.cabal && git switch branch`

Above works. What does it tell about the moment of recomputation?

#### Important

Final thing is that the recomputation could be triggered from different source. I don't remember from where it comes from, but my terminal displays ghc version for the stack project on the side. My only idea on what triggers this is `stack --bash-completion-script`. I have default manjaro zsh config with stack from aur. Is there some deamon waiting to stage some changes right when before switch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you version control the `.cabal` file if it's auto-generated from `package.yaml`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think you're touching an old [discussion](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5210). I have no strong feelings here and could just untrack .cabal (simmilarly as I can still be using the trick from my post). But I think the question remains as both solutions are workarounds.